# Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2" in Laravel dogital ocean server

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8, digital-ocean

Found this error.
PHP Version - 8.1.7
Composer Version - 2.3.7
Laravel Version - 8
Also added write permission in storage folder.
Already check lots of solution like -
[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arHMK.jpg)

1. php artisan key:generate
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan config:clear
4. rm -rf app/storage/logs/laravel.logs
5. php artisan cache:clear
6. composer dump-autoload

Please help me to solve this out. Digital ocean

Comment: Usually, specially on *nix systems, you can have different PHP versions through the web server and CLI. When you checked PHP, did you do phpinfo() through the web server or did you run `php -v` in the terminal? Also, what OS are you using? "Digital Ocean" only tell us who's hosting it, but nothing about your environment since they offer multiple solutions.

Comment: I just checked in both way while check using terminal i found PHP version 8.1.7 again while checking phpinfo() I found 7.4.3

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem. By reading the title of this post, I would assume that the error message is a pretty clear one?

Answer (score -1):

- you can try it by adding --ignore-platform-reqs after composer command

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Wouldn't this approach contain pretty serious downsides?